# Low-Latency IPC Between UI Thread and Child Process in C#

Tags: c#, process, ipc, shared-memory

I have program that spawns a separate child process that performs a function that can potentially run for a long period of time. While the child process is running, a windows form is displayed on the main thread (this has to be on the main thread) showing the progress of the child process. I need to set up IPC in order to communicate the current progress state of the child process on the main UI thread. I was able to get an anonymous pipeline set up, however there was significant lag. Are there any recommendations for a faster method? I have read that using Memory-Mapped Files can reduce latency even further, however I am having trouble setting this up.

Comment: It just doesn't matter, all IPC mechanism operate at the same speed.  They all solve the same problem, just in different ways.  The underlying operation is fundamentally the same, it requires shared memory and a thread context switch.  The other ways are convenient because you don't have to solve the synchronization problems that raw MMFs require you to solve.  The kind of problem you *really* don't want to have to solve.  Named pipes and local loopback sockets are fine as well.  .NET adds remoting and WCF.  If you notice lag from *only* reporting progress then you are doing it wrong.

Comment: Do you absolutely have to use a separate process? Can't you employ worker threads within your main process?

Comment: I would want it be on a separate thread as well, however that is not possible due to stability issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the buffer sizes to 0 and/or flushing the pipe after a write?

Comment: Are you talking about for an anonymous pipe? No I don't think I did that. Is that always necessary to do?

Comment: well, to improve throughput, it's likely to be buffered (fewer context switches), as low latency isn't always important. When latency is important, eliminate the buffer or force a flush.

Comment: In case anyone is wondering I tried using an anonymous pipe again, making sure to flush the pipe after ever write and this helped improve the latency.